# What is the "Participation" user sort on Meta sites?

Tags: support, users, per-site-meta, sorting

I notice that users on per-site metas are, by default, sorted by something called "participation". I would assume this to be Meta-pseudo-rep, but it seems that someone who has basically no Meta activity and pretty much only votes can hold 2<sup>nd</sup> place in this sort.

- What is the formula for this?
- Why can't it be adjusted for different timeframes (e.g. week, month,
- Can we have this sort on main sites?